# Spark workers stopped after driver commanded a shutdown

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

Basically, Master node also perform as a one of the slave. Once slave on master completed it called the SparkContext to stop and hence this command propagate to all the slaves which stop the execution in mid of the processing.

Error log in one of the worker:

> INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: attempt_201612061001_0008_m_000005_18112: Committed
>
> INFO Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 18112). 2536 bytes result sent to driver
>
> INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
>
> ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERMtdown

Comment: I got the same error - for no obvious reason, a structured streaming job is terminated by the driver, although according to the log file there is still lots of memory available for the driver.

Comment: Did you find what causing to ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Answer (score 4):

Check your resource manager user interface, in case you see any executor failed - it details about memory error. However if executor has not failed but still driver called for shut down - usually this is due to driver memory, please try to increase driver memory. Let me know how it goes.